# What’s so special about virgins’ blood?

Tags: internal-consistency

For some bizarre reason, most cultists are obsessed with opening portal, doing summoning, etc. But they also seem to share the same need of virgin’s blood for their spells. Now a smart cultist tried to used blood from random humans, but that failed spectacularly.

But the question becomes: Why is virgin’s so special in use of these spells?

NOTE: I am not looking for answers such as ‘Because magic’ or ‘Because the spell needed it’. I am looking for logical, or explainable answers.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Generic Person! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6168) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods. Have fun!

Comment: SE uses a one-specific-question/one-best-answer model. You need to edit your Q or it'll be closed. Right now you're asking for an [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6139#6139), we need to change that to a [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6138#6138) or it'll be closed as [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/idea-refinement-clarification-and-examples-of-vtc-reasons-for-new-users/6437#6437).

Comment: without a detailed explanation of your magic system, the answer can only be "because magic" Why does X need Y without knowing what X is, is an unanswerable question.

Comment: Here's a dark idea: The demons drag the victim to hell.  Virgins haven't done anything to merit hell, so the demons are gaining something instead of getting the same person they already would have gotten later.

Answer (score 14):

As the demons are summoned the summoning process exposes them to any diseases or afflictions that the sacrificial victim may be carrying, in particular blood-borne diseases and STDs of the host. The use of virgin sacrifices was originally to reduce those risks and they haven't really caught up with the modern technology that would allow a medical screening to be used instead.

Comment: [It's something that vampires have to watch out for too...](https://vimeo.com/43187299)

Comment: I couldn’t help but laugh at this.

Answer (score 7):

A hypothesis says that "virgin blood" didn't initially mean "blood of a virgin", but "blood that was never used in a ritual before". Although there is to my knowledge little proof to confirm or invalidate this theory.

If your subscribe to that idea, one could suppose using the blood of a person in a magic ritual consumes a power within that blood, or taints it, rending it improper for other uses.

Answer (score 6):

It could also be a sacrifice of a loss of potential.

Take the phrase "Women and children first".
Youth is valued over age, and women over men, because of the potential implied. Once you are old you've lived most of your life, done most of the things that you will do, contributed the most that you will contribute.
Now, it could be argued that the loss of knowledge and experience that age brings should be more valuable than potential knowledge and experience, but for some reason it isn't. 
Likewise, women are valued over men because of the potential to bring new life into the world.

So the power inherent in being a virgin is the power of potential that you lose once you've given yourself to another.

Comment: While I generally agree with your statements about valuing potential, what about virgins makes their potential greater? Or put another way, what potential is lost when a virgin first has sex?

Comment: @Gene It could be that you give a piece of your soul away when you have sex, especially the first time. "You always remember your first" or something like that. If it sets up a soul tie to that person, then you lose the potential of that with others down the road, and that could be the potential that the ritual needs.

Answer (score 3):

**It relates to the quality of the sacrifice.**

Virgin's were considered pure -- although this is arguably a result of Roman Catholic doctrine, this would ignore the even older history of purity of the sacrifice being important -- thus the sacrificing of children.

The greater boon you desire from your deity, the greater the sacrifice is necessary. Animal sacrifice < Human sacrifice < Virgin sacrifice.

Evil deities in particular avail themselves of the additional power that comes from greater sacrifices of human and virgins in particular.

There is not much historical evidence of virgin sacrifice, though human and infant sacrifices are well documented. Virgin sacrifice is more likely a trope that represents the idea of greater sacrifice in modern literature, movies, etc. because it is not as disturbing to modern thought as child sacrifice. And it gives the story teller the option of sexually related plot points.

Comment: I'm curious why specifically *Roman* Catholic, and not, for example, Greek Catholic, or simply "Catholic", or even generally "Christian", or, even more generally, "religious" doctrine. For example, in the Trojan cycle, Agamemnon was compelled to sacrifice Iphigenia so that his ships could sail for Troy.

Comment: @AlexP exactly.  Virgin sacrifice is **old**.

Comment: @AlexP -- that's why I said it could be argued. Many people associate virginity as being more pure than say marriage as a Roman (or more broadly Catholic doctrine) it is in fact older as stated.

Answer (score 3):

How about playing on this: https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2017/08/15/male-dna-is-often-found-in-womens-brains-where-does-it-come-from/#221800877459

Now, you don't need to say that every women that has sex has some "impurity" in her, but you could argue that the impurity comes from pregnancy, and the only safe assumtion is to use blood of a woman that cannot have been pregnant, a virgin.
Then add some story that male blood has some specific compontent that makes the rituals impossible and thus you need pure blood from a human female.

Answer (score 3):

In general, virgins are seen as innocent, unsullied things that are usually younger. There could be many reasons for this.

Generally speaking, virgins are assumed to be younger. We can normally assume a young teenager is a virgin, and we assume anyone over 30 isn't. Whether this is true depends on many factors such as culture, health, religion, and so on. Most cultures around the world value a young life as more important.

#### Medical

As Tim B said, a virgin has a lower chance of STDs. In the real world there still is a chance, since people can easily get herpes. WebMD even has figures that show that 1 in 5 people over the age of 12 carry HSV-2.

#### Magic

In a fantasy setting, a virgin (since they're usually younger) don't have as many influences. They can be trained or molded or brainwashed or tortured to be whatever the villain wants. Also, a virgin probably wouldn't have as much life experience so have a lesser chance of being evil or harboring some power that could thwart the villain.

#### Lost Potential

As AndyD273 stated, there is a loss of potential. From a magical point of view, that could be actual power. Subsequent births can increase chances of birth defects (caused by mother's age), health risks to the mother (such as gestational diabetes), or miscarriage. So a virgin is viewed as property, much like a towel. Would you rather a fresh, new towel or an old dingy stained towel?

Answer (score 1):

A virgin is someone who has never had sex, so for virginity to be important then the act of first having sex must do something to the body to make it no longer suitable for the rituals.

One explanation for this, a handwavey magical one, is that the rituals and sacrifice rely on a certain essence or passion contained in humans that is spent with the first act of intercourse.

For a slightly more (pseudo) science answer you could say that sex releases a hormone (or starts the production of a hormone) that spoils the blood and makes it unsuitable for the rituals.